# how to affect an element's width by one child element but not others using CSS

Tags: html, css

As the title describes, I would like find a CSS means of making one element's width affect its parent element's width, but force other children of that parent to fit within that width.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div id="leftToolBar" class="toolbar">
    <div id="canvasHolder"></div>
    <div>   
            <a id="tool_pencil" onclick="setTool('pencil'); return false;" href="#" class="currentTool"><img src="images/pencil.png"/></a>
            <a id="tool_paintbrush" onclick="setTool('paintbrush'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/paint.png"/></a>
            <a id="tool_floodfill" onclick="setTool('floodfill'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/bucketfill.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="transform('shiftleft'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/left.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="transform('shiftright'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/right.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="transform('shiftdown'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/down.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="transform('shiftup'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/up.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="transform('rotleft'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/rotateleft.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="transform('rotright'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/rotateright.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="transform('diagonal1'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/dflip1.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="transform('diagonal2'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/dflip2.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="transform('vflip'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/vflip.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="transform('hflip'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/hflip.png"/></a>
            <a onclick="toggleGrid(); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/grid.png"/></a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And here is the relevant css (thus far):

```
    .toolbar a{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 24px;
            border-radius: 0.2em;
            padding: 3px;
            border: 1px solid #AAA;
    }

    .toolbar a.currentTool{
            box-shadow:-1px -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset, 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;
            border: none;
    }

    #canvasHolder {
            background-color: #a0a0a0;
            border: 1px solid #777470;
    }

    #canvasHolder canvas{
            border: 1px solid #666;
            background: repeating-linear-gradient(
                    45deg,
                    #CCC,
                    #CCC 2px,
                    #CCC 4px,
                    #AAA 6px
            );
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: center;
    }
```

This of course is not doing what I want.  I would like the "canvasHolder" div to determine the size of that toolbar beyond a certain minimum, and for the anchors in the div below it to populate the area below, but without affecting the width of the "leftToolBar" div.

Is there some combination of CSS attributes I can apply here (aside from a hard-coded "max-width" number) that will give me that effect?

Comment: I am going to try doing something like this with `flexbox`, and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div id="leftToolBar" class="toolbar">
<div id="canvasHolder"></div> 
<div>
        <a class="currentTool"><img src="images/pencil.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/paint.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/bucketfill.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/left.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/right.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/down.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/up.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/rotateleft.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/rotateright.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/dflip1.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/dflip2.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/vflip.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/hflip.png"/></a>
        <a><img src="images/grid.png"/></a>
</div>
</div>
<style>
.toolbar {
  background-color: green;
  width: min-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.toolbar a {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 24px;
        border-radius: 0.2em;
        padding: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #AAA;
}

.toolbar a.currentTool{
        box-shadow:-1px -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset, 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;
        border: none;
}

#canvasHolder {
        background-color: #a0a0a0;
        border: 1px solid #777470;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
</style>
```

Does this accomplish what you are looking for?

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!  The only drawback that I could see to it is that it currently requires a very up-to-date browser.  Not a problem in my case.

Comment: @Jacob I am glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no -- CSS does not have a parent selector. The best you can do is give `#canvasHolder` a `min-width` and `max-width`, or a percentage-based width.

You could target it with jQuery, and manipulate the parent CSS through there, using `$("#canvasHolder").parent().css();`, assuming you have access to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but take a look:

```css
.toolbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24px;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
}

.toolbar a.currentTool {
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset, 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;
    border: none;
}

#canvasHolder {
    background-color: #a0a0a0;
    border: 1px solid #777470;
}

#canvasHolder canvas {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #CCC, #CCC 2px, #CCC 4px, #AAA 6px);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: center;
}


/** important part **/

.toolbar {
    /*background-color: red;*/
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#canvasHolder {
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

#canvasHolder + div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftToolBar" class="toolbar">
    <div id="canvasHolder"></div>
    <div>
        <a id="tool_pencil" onclick="setTool('pencil'); return false;" href="#" class="currentTool"><img src="images/pencil.png" /></a>
        <a id="tool_paintbrush" onclick="setTool('paintbrush'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/paint.png" /></a>
        <a id="tool_floodfill" onclick="setTool('floodfill'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/bucketfill.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="transform('shiftleft'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/left.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="transform('shiftright'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/right.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="transform('shiftdown'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/down.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="transform('shiftup'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/up.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="transform('rotleft'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/rotateleft.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="transform('rotright'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/rotateright.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="transform('diagonal1'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/dflip1.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="transform('diagonal2'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/dflip2.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="transform('vflip'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/vflip.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="transform('hflip'); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/hflip.png" /></a>
        <a onclick="toggleGrid(); return false;" href="#"><img src="images/grid.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I understood what you are trying to do, the div with the links should be removed from the flow so that `#canvasHolder` can determine its parent width.

For this to be done we need to:

- Set `.toolbar` width to auto so its width is determined by its first child;
- Set `position: absolute` on the links container div, so it is removed from the current flow. Also set `top: 100%` to make it be placed always at the end of its parent and `width: 100%` to make it stretch with `#canvasHolder`;
- And set a `min-width` on `#canvasHolder`.

You can change the width of `#canvasHolder` to see the results.